# Can't use ncurses libraries

Tags: 16.04, package-management, compiling, ncurses

It says it requires the ncurses libraries but I already have those installed.

```
$ make menuconfig
find vendors -mindepth 2 '(' -name .svn -prune ')' -o -type f -name Kconfig -print | sed 's:^:source ../:' > vendors/Kconfig
config/mkconfig > Kconfig
KCONFIG_NOTIMESTAMP=1 /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/uClinux-dist/config/kconfig/mconf Kconfig


*** End of Linux kernel configuration.
*** Execute 'make' to build the kernel or try 'make help'.

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/uClinux-dist'
KCONFIG_NOTIMESTAMP=1 make ARCH=nios2   CROSS_COMPILE=nios2-linux-gnu- O=/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/uClinux-dist/linux-2.6.x -C ../linux-2.6 menuconfig
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6'
  GEN     /home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/uClinux-dist/linux-2.6.x/Makefile
 *** Unable to find the ncurses libraries or the
 *** required header files.
 *** 'make menuconfig' requires the ncurses libraries.
 *** 
 *** Install ncurses (ncurses-devel) and try again.
 *** 
make[4]: *** [scripts/kconfig/dochecklxdialog] Error 1
make[3]: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/linux-2.6'
make[1]: *** [linux_menuconfig] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/developer/altera/nios2-linux/uClinux-dist'
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

Looks like I already got it:

```
 sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'ncurses-dev'
libncurses5-dev is already the newest version (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Which ncurses library packages do you have installed?

Comment: @muru I updated the question with additional info. The `make menuconfig` used to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the libraries, it should be enough to bypass the error compiler giving you.

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

If the command didn't do the trick, there could be another problem coming somewhere else. Feel free to report back if you found anything else.

Comment: It says `libncurses5-dev is already the newest version (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1).`

Comment: Use apt to re-install libncurses5-dev in case any files have been (unwisely) moved or deleted: `sudo apt install --reinstall libncurses5-dev`